# Using variant in Bison and Flex

Tags: c++, c++17, bison, lex, variant

I've been rewriting a parser from c to c++, and as such I am trying to use variant with my code. However, I am not sure how to integrate it with flex, and I keep getting esoteric error messages.

My bison file looks like

```
%require "3"
%language "c++"

%{
    // declarations
%}

%define api.value.type {std::variant<double, std::string>}

%token COMMENT
%token <double> DOUBLE
%token <std::string> STRING

// grammar
```

and my lexer looks like

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%option noyywrap

ID [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*


%%
[ \t\n ]+ ;

\-?[0-9]+ |
\-?[0-9]+\. |
\-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ |
\-?\.[0-9]+ { yylval.emplace<double>(std::atof(yytext)); return DOUBLE;}
// other tokens
zA-Z][\.a-zA-Z0-9_]* { yylval.emplace<std::string>(yytext); return STRING;}
%%
```

I am not sure of my usage of yylval, I am trying to access the variant as I would have with the `%union`.

I get the following error:

```
y.tab.h:125:18: error: ‘variant’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
     typedef std::variant<double, std::string> semantic_type;
                  ^~~~~~~
y.tab.h:197:27: error: ‘semantic_type’ does not name a type
                     const semantic_type& v);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
y.tab.h:212:7: error: ‘semantic_type’ does not name a type
       semantic_type value;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
my_mdl.l: In function ‘int yylex()’:
my_mdl.l:16:3: error: ‘yylval’ was not declared in this scope
 \-?\.[0-9]+ { yylval.emplace<double>(std::atof(yytext)); return DOUBLE;}
   ^~~~~~
my_mdl.l:16:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘yylex’
 \-?\.[0-9]+ { yylval.emplace<double>(std::atof(yytext)); return DOUBLE;}
   ^~~~~~
   yylex
my_mdl.l:16:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
 \-?\.[0-9]+ { yylval.emplace<double>(std::atof(yytext)); return DOUBLE;}
                  ^~~~~~
my_mdl.l:16:53: error: ‘DOUBLE’ was not declared in this scope
 \-?\.[0-9]+ { yylval.emplace<double>(std::atof(yytext)); return DOUBLE;}
                                                     ^~~~~~
my_mdl.l:18:10: error: ‘COMMENT’ was not declared in this scope
 "//".* { return COMMENT;}
          ^~~~~~~
my_mdl.l:37:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
 [a-zA-Z][\.a-zA-Z0-9_]* { yylval.emplace<std::string>(yytext); return STRING;}
                             ^
my_mdl.l:37:47: error: ‘STRING’ was not declared in this scope
 [a-zA-Z][\.a-zA-Z0-9_]* { yylval.emplace<std::string>(yytext); return STRING;}
                                               ^~~~~~
```

I also get a few hundred lines of errors from my `.y` file such as

```
my_mdl.y:88:79: error: no matching function for call to ‘MOVE::MOVE(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
     p.add_command(Command{in_place_index<5>, MOVE( {{$2, $3, $4}}, $5)});
                                                                               ^
In file included from parsing/symt.h:7:0,
                 from my_mdl.y:10:
parsing/cmd.h:44:5: note: candidate: MOVE::MOVE(const Scalable<double, 3>&, const string&)
     MOVE(const Scalable<double, 3> &params, const std::string &scaleFactorName);
     ^~~~
```

`MOVE` is a struct defined as

```
struct MOVE {
    MOVE(const Scalable<double, 3> &params, const std::string &scaleFactorName);

    Scalable<double, 3> params; // todo equationify
    std::string scale_factor_name;
};
```

and it is one of the types in the variant (`std::variant<MOVE, etc...> Command`). The strange thing is that this works normally in my code if I write
`p.add_command(Command{in_place_index<5>, MOVE{{{x, y, z}}, "asdfads"}});`

Comment: Do you really need to handle variants by yourselves?  Why don't you rely on Bison to handle these details?  See https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#C_002b_002b-Variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included enough of your program to allow for a precise answer. Please see the SO help page on preparing a [mcse]. But it seems likely that you get the error

```
y.tab.h:125:18: error: ‘variant’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
```

because you haven't arranged for `#include <variant>` to be in your flex file.

The typedef itself is from the generated code in the header file produced by bison, but bison cannot guess what `#include` directives it might need, so it leaves it up to you to insert them. You must ensure that all types needed by your semantic type have been defined before you `#include` the bison-generated header. You could insert appropriate `#include` directives in the prologue block in your flex file, or you could use a [`%code requires`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#index-_0025code-requires-2) block in your bison file. (Since you are using bison 3, the latter is probably the best solution.)

I have no idea what `SAVE` means in the errors from your bison file. I assume it is a macro you have (or have not defined), so the error would be a result of the macro expansion.

Comment: Defining variant worked! I will update the question details about the SAVE bug

Comment: @Simon: I'm pretty sure that bison will insert a case operation to turn the variant type into the specific type for each grammar symbol. That works for unions but not for `std::variant`. I honestly don't know how you would work around that but if something occurs to me, I'll leave a note.

Answer (score 2):

Bison actually provides its *own* custom type called 'variant', which is *not* the C++ `std::variant`, and supports it nicely.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#C_002b_002b-Variants

> Bison provides a variant based implementation of semantic values for C++. This alleviates all the limitations reported in the previous section, and in particular, object types can be used without pointers.

> To enable variant-based semantic values, set the %define variable api.value.type to variant (see %define Summary). Then %union is ignored; instead of using the name of the fields of the %union to “type” the symbols, use genuine types.

> For instance, instead of:

```
%union
{
  int ival;
  std::string* sval;
}
%token <ival> NUMBER;
%token <sval> STRING;
```

> write:

```
%token <int> NUMBER;
%token <std::string> STRING;
```

> STRING is no longer a pointer, which should fairly simplify the user actions in the grammar and in the scanner (in particular the memory management).

To enable it, you simply specify

```
%define api.value.type variant
```

However this will also affect your lexer. I put together a small demo C++ flex/bison skeleton using the latest flex/bison binaries under Ubuntu:

https://github.com/kfsone/flub

highlights being:

```
/* lexer */
{string}            yylval->emplace<std::string>(yytext); return Token::STRING;
```

```
/* parser */
%language "C++"
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%require "3.8.2"

%define         api.value.type      variant
/*
%define         api.value.automove     // use with care
*/

%define         parse.assert
%define         parse.trace
%define         parse.error         detailed
%define         parse.lac           full

/* ... */

/*
 NB: You now use the TYPE rather than union-member name
*/
%token <std::string> STRING

/*
// ditto for nterms, but I now prefer putting them by the production itself.
%nterm <string::string> string_literal
*/
%%

/* ... */

/* Declare the type of this non-terminal, to be done here in the
   productions section, you need a trailing semicolon */
%nterm <std::string> using_file;
using_file
  : "using" STRING
    { $$ = $2; }
  ;
```

You can then use a much more modern AST-building approach, one thing I found helpful was to have a wrapper type of my own that captured a value AND its location.

```
template<typename ValueType>
struct ParsedType
{
  location  mLoc;  // or YourParserType::location_type
  ValueType mValue;
};

using ParsedString = ParsedType<std::string>;

/* ... */

%nterm <ParsedString> using_file;
using_file
    :    "using" STRING
         { $$ = ParsedString(@2, $2); }
```